# HashMap changes the values references

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

I have a problem with the HashMap. It changes the references stored as values when new Key-Value-Pairs are inserted.

I use the HashMap for quicker access to Objects that are otherwise stored in a very hierarchical structure. When the first pair was inserted, its address and the original address are identical. After adding another pair, the address stored in the HashMap is changed. Therefor I cant the original Objects through the HashMap.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code how I construct the HashMap. In the second method, in the first for-loop the above described happens.

```
private Map<String, Parameter> createRefMap(Settings settings) {
    Map<String, Parameter> result = new HashMap<String, Parameter>();
    for (ParameterList parameterList : settings.getParameterList()) {
        result.putAll(createRefMap(parameterList, "SETTINGS"));
    }

    return result;
}

private Map<String, Parameter> createRefMap(ParameterList parameterList, String preLevel) {
    Map<String, Parameter> result = new HashMap<String, Parameter>();
    String level = preLevel + "/" + parameterList.getName();

    for (Parameter parameter : parameterList.getParameter()) {
        result.put(level + "/" + parameter.getName(), parameter);
    }

    for (ParameterList innerParameterList : parameterList.getParameterList()) {
        result.putAll(createRefMap(innerParameterList, level));
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is how I call it

```
this.actRefMap = createRefMap(this.actAppSettings);
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Can you paste some code for the problem you are facing please ?

Comment: What do you mean 'the address is changed'? You should use key to get the object stored in the HashMap.

Comment: @ntalbs I assume he means that the object being in the hashMap and the object in the hierarchy is not the same any more so changes to objects retrieved from the hashmap does not occur in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing any of your code (or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so I'll quote the first paragraph of [`HashMap` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): _HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time._

Comment: @MartinLarsson Thats right! I posted some code..

Comment: @jlordo I could not yet reproduce this in a SSCCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, if you do something like this:

```
System.out.println(thing1.toString());
myMap.put(key1, thing1);
myMap.put(key2, thing2);
System.out.println(thing1.toString());
```

that the second println will somehow print out results from a different object?  Is it any particular object, or just one at random?  What you state as your problem is not possible; it would break an unthinkable number of java programs.

Part of your assertion is that the "address" changes; I'm not sure what you mean by that.  The object id, visible in many debuggers?  physical memory address?  Again, if either of these things happened, Map would be broken.

If your actual problem is that some other reference to thing1 no longer has the contents of the reference in the map, then you are changing that external reference to thing1 somewhere.

Comment: I just found it. As always it is really embarrassing, but I do change the map in another part of my application. The above code is part of a Model, which passes the HashMap as part of a ModelEvent to the View, where the Map is being edited. I do now sent copies of the Map in my Events.